# Can one express combinations as sets and permutations as tuples?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

What exactly is correct way (mathematically) to express a combination?

For instance if I have $3$ objects $O_1$, $O_2$, $O_3$ so if I simply write $O_1O_2O_3$, it's impossible to tell whether what I have here is a permutation or a combination.

I understand one way to counter this problem would be to simply mention whether it's a combination or a permutation but I was wondering, is there a mathematical **notation** as such to write a permutation or a combination without ambiguity?

I thought of writing writing combination as a set like $\{ O_1,O_2,O_3 \}$ which conveys the point that order isn't necessary. Similarly I could use tuples for permutations but my professor told me it's a bad idea, he did explain it briefly (something along the lines a combination isn't exactly a set...blah blah) but I honestly didn't understand him, hence this question.

Hoping someone would give me a better way to visualise and express combinations and permutations (I understand what they are, just can't properly write it out because of notation problems)

Thank you!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using set notation $\{O_1, O_2\}$ for sets and tuple notation $(O_1, O_2)$ for permutations.  It just depends on your context. e.g. sometimes it's more useful to use function notation for permutations.

Comment: I disagree with your professor; a combination _is_ exactly a set.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I disagree with him tooo. I guess I'm just out here seeking a validation more than an answer.

Comment: @JairTaylor Well my good sir, please tell me how a function is used for permutations? I've never heard about it! Maybe something like $f(i)= O_i$ or something?

Comment: @William Right, that would be one way to define a permutation: a bijection $f$ from $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\}$ to your set $\{O_1, \ldots, O_n\}$.  The most common definition of a permutation is a bijection $f: \{1,2, \ldots, n\} \rightarrow \{1,2, \ldots, n\}$, an element of the symmetric group $S_n$.  But "permutation" can mean slightly different things depending on context - e.g., if $S$ is a set that doesn't have any particular order, a permutation of $S$ is a bijection $f: S \rightarrow S$, but we wouldn't use tuple notation here because we don't have a notion of the "first" element of $S$.

Comment: @JairTaylor I lost you at "$S$ is a set that doesn't any particular order", what kind of order are we talking about here? Isn't a set supposed to be order-less collection of objects

Comment: @William Right, you could just say "a set".  But a lot of times a set will have one particular ordering that is usually used - e.g., a subset of the integers.  Here I mean a "generic" set like $\{$red, blue, Bob, Paris$\}$ with no particular structure - or one where we've purposefully forgotten about any such structure.

Comment: @JairTaylor also why does it have to be a bijection? A permutation can have some objects repeated right? For instance what if $O_1=O_2$?

Comment: @William No, they must be distinct.

Comment: @JairTaylor what about this? https://brilliant.org/wiki/permutations-with-repetition/

Answer (score 0):

You are right and your professor is wrong - the combination $n \choose k$ is **exactly** the number of $k$-element subsets of a set with $n$ elements.  In many combinatorics textbooks, that is the actual definition given.

Your notion of tuples as permutations isn't going to work.  The issue is that $(1, 1, 1)$ is a perfectly valid triple of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, but it is not a permutation because of the repeated values.  An accurate way of thinking about is that the permutation $_3P_5$ is the number of injective (i.e. one-to-one) mappings from $\{1,2,3\}$ to $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.  Then the factorial $5!={_5P_5}$ is the number of bijections on $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Comment: Not every tuple represents a permutation, but you can represent every permutation by a tuple, so I don't see a problem with that notation.

Comment: But a permutation can have repeated values if I allow repetition right?

Comment: @William There are absolutely combinatorics problems that count tuples with repeated values, but it would confuse everyone around you if you described those as "permutations".

Comment: @MatthewDaly then what does one describe those as?

Comment: @MatthewDaly also see, https://brilliant.org/wiki/permutations-with-repetition/

Comment: @William That's just another definition of a different object, a permutation-with-repetition, or multiset permutation, that in general is not a permutation.  If you just say 'permutation' without further explanation, it is assumed that the elements will be distinct.  Words aren't always completely standardized in math - you just have to communicate what you mean.